# Fazer a união do conteúdo de duas listas considerando os índices em Python?

Tags: python, lista, join

O cenário é o seguinte, tenho duas listas, ex:

```
 list1 = [1,2,3,4]
 list2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

Quero gerar uma lista nova que fique assim:

```
[15,26,37,48]
```

Ou seja, que "junte" os elementos de cada índice.
Fiz a concatenação assim, mas a lista ficou assim:

```
[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

Poderia usa `join` para ter a saída que quero?
Ambas as listas possuem o mesmo tamanho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que os valores sempre têm apenas um dígito, uma opção é fazer as contas - os números da primeira lista correspondem à dezena, e os da segunda lista correspondem à unidade, então basta multiplicar o primeiro por 10 e somar com o segundo:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

result = []
for n1, n2 in zip(list1, list2):
    result.append(10 * n1 + n2)

print(result) # [15, 26, 37, 48]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) percorre ambas as listas ao mesmo tempo, então a cada iteração do `for`, `n1` será um número da `list1` e `n2` será um número da `list2`.

O detalhe é que o *loop* é encerrado quando a menor das listas terminar, mas como você disse que ambas têm o mesmo tamanho, isso não será um problema.

Se quiser, também pode usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

result = [ 10 * n1 + n2 for n1, n2 in zip(list1, list2) ]

print(result) # [15, 26, 37, 48]
```

---

[`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) serve para juntar várias strings em uma só, então não serviria para o seu caso.

E provavelmente alguém vai sugerir transformar os números em strings, concatená-las e transformar em número de novo. Algo assim:

```
result = []
for n1, n2 in zip(list1, list2):
    result.append(int(str(n1) + str(n2)))
```

Mas eu acho uma volta desnecessária. Se as listas só têm números, eu acho mais simples fazer as contas, em vez de ficar convertendo para string e depois de volta para número.

Comment: Obrigada!
Deu certo aqui, estou aprendendo Python agora, não conhecia o zip nem o termo pythônica, mais itens para estudo :)